# Can't initialize VM's on HyperV Windows Server 2012

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I'm really stuck with this and I can't understand why I sunddendly can't make ANY VM to start succesfully in my system.

I had just one VM, and it was working perfectly, then for some reasons I booted into another system, then came back into WinServer 2012 and couldn't make them start anymore.

This is the traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-VM Ubuntu
Start-VM : 'Ubuntu' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 1ECB1603-A320-4BAF-8452-9962768F5D49)
You do not have permission to perform the operation. Contact your administrator if you believe you should have
permission to perform this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-VM Ubuntu
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied:  (Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMTask:VMTask) [Start-VM], Virtualization
OperationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :  AccessDenied,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVMCommand
```

Seems clearly to be a permission issue of course, but I just don't get it, how?

I deleted my previous VM, not before I had it exported, THEN created a new VM, with new ID, using the same disk, same error above.

I even created a new one, without any disk, same error.

Does anyone know what could have happened?

Is there some script or configuration I should look for?

I've searched and searched even on `msdn` but nothing, I dont get it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**

And, if I start it from HyperV's graphic interface, then it shows `An error occurred while attempting to start the selected virtual machine(s) 'Ubuntu' could not initialize (Virtual machine ID 'ID')`

**SECOND EDIT**

Following User @Peter Hahndorf suggestion, I ran `icacls.exe` and this is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents> icacls .\Hyper-V
.\Hyper-V BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrators:(F)
  BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
  CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines:(R,WD,AD)
  NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines:(CI)(IO)(GR,WD,AD)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

It surely is about permissions, but how? I didn't "touch" anything, the folder is now placed under `C:\Users\Public\Documents` instead of `C:\Users\Administrator\My Documents`

How can I grant Administrator permission again?

Comment: I take it you have a domain controller and AD installed to another system that this system authenticates to?  OR is this stand alone without domain controllers and active directory...

Comment: Could the "other system" have disabled the ability to run virtual machines in the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: @Citizen No, this is standalone :(

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well, actually, I just installed Windows 7 Home edition on another partition, could it be that? :/ sounds weird to me... One never knows tho

Comment: @NeoVe It seems a bit unlikely that installing Windows 7 would change the BIOS/UEFI settings to allow running VMs, however, you should check the relevant settings. If you happen to have updated the BIOS then they are likely to have been reset.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you running the PowerShell command from an elevated console?

Comment: Hi @BenN please, check my second edit, any idea about it? Thank You!

Comment: And Yes, I'm on PS console with admin privileges